# Request session ID is different every time ExpressJS and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

This is my front end code with react where I try to make a simple login

```js
  const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:4000'

  async function login(email,password){
      const data = {
        Email: email, 
        Password: password
      }
    const response = await  fetch(serverUrl+'/login',{
      method:'POST',
      credentials:'include',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    const outcome = await response.json()
    console.log(response.status)
    if(response.status === 200) {
      dispatch(authActions.login())

    }
    if(response.status === 404) {
      error(outcome.message)
    }
  }
```

Now the issue I have is every single time I press on the login button the session ID is different, which now gives me issue when I try to make session

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}))

//Method to login a user
app.use('/login', (request,response)=>{
  console.log(request.session)
  console.log(request.sessionID)
  console.log(request.session.id)
})
```

Comment: if the session ID change it mean each login is different or the session expired / destroyed, how do you set your session setting on the backend ?

Comment: I am not creating sessions. All I am trying to do understand why I have different sessions id after every requests

Comment: session id change when you create a new session after you put a login request, unless the session is not expired or destroyed and your new request 's credential (on the cookie) match the current session. It also can depend if is resave, or regenerate, But for the session MaxAge property you need to set up the session.